# Array .length property returning 0 for document.getElementsByClassName in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have a list of `li` elements with one class in my HTML. I want to grab them all and place them in an array and then find out how many have I grabbed. However, whenever I try to output the `.length` property of the array that the `document.getElementsByClassName` is in, it is just resulting to `0`. Here's my code:

```
function activateFeedMain() {
        console.log('Function Called');
        var clickInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('miniInfo');
        var showInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('moreInfo');

        console.log(clickInfo.length);
    }

    activateFeedMain();
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta id="refresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
<title>News and Events</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/hfreplacement.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/news.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #content-col1 ul {list-style-type: none;}
    #content-col1 ul li {background-color: #66FFCC; border-radius: 5px; padding: 12px; margin-bottom: 8px;}
    #content-col1 ul li:hover {background-color: #FFFFCC;}
    .description {font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;}
    .date, .type, .approval {font-size: 12pt; padding-right: 25px; padding-left: 18px; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid black;}
    .date {padding-left: 0px;}
    .approval {border: none;}
    .invisible {display: none;}
    #content-col1 ul a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
    #content-col1 ul a {text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="head"></div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="content-col1">
        <p class="note">Refresh for updates</p>
        <script>newsContent();</script>
    </div>

    <div id="content-col2">
        <h1>Latest</h1>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="foot"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function activateFeedMain() {
        console.log('Function Called');
        var clickInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('miniInfo');
        var showInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('moreInfo');

        console.log(clickInfo.length);
    }

    activateFeedMain();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Script`newsContent();` installs all the `li`s in the `ul`. On a side note, when I use `console.log(clickInfo)` it is giving me the list of array. Something has to do with the `.length` property...

Also, when I try to use `console.log(clickInfo[1]);`, it's giving me undefined...

Comment: I just corrected it, and it still returned the same value... :(

Comment: Where on your page is this script located?

Comment: Please provide your html as well.

Comment: The script is located at the end. I'll post the HTML in just a min.

Comment: I don't see any elements with class `miniInfo` or `moreInfo` in the markup. Are you absolutely certain they are created by the call to `newsContent()`?

Comment: It is dynamically added as the page loads. Notice the `newsContent();` script... It loads up all of the list items as soon as the page loads.

Comment: The newsContent() is loading perfectly. The console.log(clickInfo) is giving me the list of array in the browser console, but it is just not letting me get the .length. It is always returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmukfq2p/)***

The reason that you're having this issue is because your `newsContent` function is dynamically creating creating the content on the page *asynchronously*, in parallel with your `activateFeedMain` function. Since they're being called at the same time, the elements from your `newsContent` function haven't been created at the time that `activateFeedMain` is being called.

You can solve this issue by giving `newsContent` a callback function that will be executed when it's finished running.

```
function activateFeedMain() {
    console.log('Function Called');
    var clickInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('miniInfo');
    var showInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('moreInfo');

    console.log(clickInfo.length);
}

// Call activateFeedMain() once newsContent has finished
newsContent(activateFeedMain);
```

And where you define `newsContent`, design it to take a callback like so:

```
function newsContent(callback){

    ...

    // When this function is done
    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because the script is at the end it doesnt mean everything else is loaded

Comment: I didn't get the callback part. I placed the exact words callback (assuming that is how it should be) as you've shown here, but another error pops up in the console... `callback is not a function`...

Comment: @SyedAmeed did you add the `callback` argument to the `newsContent` function?

Comment: Do I have to change anything by the `newsContent();` (the one that is calling newsContent to load on page)? Or do I have to add `newsContent(activateFeedMain);`  to start the `activateFeedMain` function at the end?

Comment: Yes, I added the call back function to the news content.

Comment: @SyedAmeed Try looking at my fiddle and seeing how I implemented this approach

Comment: @NickZuber Thanks so much. This was a life saver!

Comment: @NickZuber Though the main issue is solved, the console is still saying that `callback();` is not a function. What should I do to get this annoying thing away?

Comment: @SyedAmeed I'm glad I could help! - Also, where is the console complaining? Is it from the `newsContent` function definition?

Comment: @SyedAmeed See my edit - Basically, before you try to execute `callback` you can just check to make sure it's a function. This should remove that console error

Comment: @NickZuber Thanks, it's gone now. :)

Comment: @SyedAmeed Glad to help!